# htaccess rewrite rule with single parameter

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

When user enters url like

```
http://example.com/app/abcd123/
```

I want to show hime page from

```
http://example.com/app/index.php?param=abcd123
```

Without changing URL in browser.

I put .htaccess file inside app folder with code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^param=(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/app/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Is `/app`/ a real directory?

Comment: yes, and i put my htaccess file there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this code in `/app/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /app/

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?param=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?param=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Wow both sides redirection(external to internal AND internal to external), this is great solution, thanks for sharing sir cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `.htaccess` code. It should help you.

Make sure the rewrite base should be the form the root to your present directory.

```
RewriteBase /app/

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?param=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

In this, if the user enters like `http://example.com/app/qwerty` the call will be processed like `http://example.com/app/index.php?params=qwerty`

This should be working, I tested it. Let me know if you face any troubles.

Comment: Thank you - code works and the only problem i faced - is that my fonts stoped to load because they are also in this folder and have links like "/app/fonts/font.ttf?ver=1.4.4"

Comment: @moonvader, anubhava's answer is the perfect one for your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php?param=$1 [L]
```

Check it there: http://htaccess.mwl.be/ or other online htaccess test service